# How can I 'replicate' an item into a list of n references to it?

Tags: java, list, copy

I have some object in Java (say a Double), and I need a list of length n, each of whose elements is a reference to that Double. I'd like an idiom for doing this, hopefully but not necessarily without using O(1) only memory.

Comment: " I'd like an idiom for doing this," what does it mean. can you explain a little more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use
[java.util.Collections.nCopies(n, value)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies%28int,%20T%29).

Comment: And this is indeed O(1) space as the resulting List object is implemented as one reference plus one int (the length).

Answer (score 1):

What about creating a data structure for this purpose?
Something like that:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class SpecialArray {
    private HashMap<Integer, Double> elements;
    private Double specialElement;
    private int size;

    public SpecialArray(Double specialElement, int size) {
        this.elements = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
        this.specialElement = specialElement;
        this.size = size;
    }

    public Double get(int index) {
        if(index<0 || index>=size) {
            return null;
        }
        if(elements.containsKey(index)) {
            return elements.get(index);
        }
        return specialElement;
    }

    public boolean add(Double d, int index) {
            if(index<0 || index>=size || elements.containsKey(index)) {
                    return false;
            }
            elements.put(index, d);
            return true;
    }
}
```

This is not a full example, of course, and can be written with generic types.
But if you have a few other elements in your list, then this can be useful, I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
Collections.fill()
```

might help you